# What is the closest thing to a logical disk image with Robocopy or similar tool?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, robocopy

I have an old 2 TB drive that seems to be on the way to electronics heaven. It's not make scary noises, but Windows 10 failed to mount it until it ran a multi-day checkdisk. Besides that, it's close to full. Time to replace it!

I have a new 3 TB drive installed as "D:", the same letter as the old drive. (The boot drive "C:" is a smallish SSD.) I want it to be as close to an exact logical copy of the old drive, even down to fiddly details like preserving directory change dates. Particularly important, I want it to preserve user file privileges.

Some years ago, I puzzled through the endless options for Robocopy and made it do a similar copy job. Foolishly, I failed to make a note of the options I used. And it seems like the list of options for Robocopy have proliferated in the intervening years.

I tried using Richcopy, but it failed to include the preserve directory dates options, and it didn't seem to want to run in Safe Mode. (I'm pretty sure the former option isn't there, but the latter may be user error.) It refused to traverse directories that were not owned by Admin.

Given the state of the 2 TB drive, some files may be unreadable. I want to keep a list of those so I can restore them from my cloud backup service. (I could probably accomplish most of these goals by restoring from the cloud service, but restoring a mostly full 2 TB drive at 20 Mbps is more than nine days, or worse if my ISP decides to throttle traffic.)

I can dig through the multitude of Robocopy options to get a workable `robocopy /options F:\* D:\` command line, but I remember that there were a lot of weird interactions between Robocopy command options.

I'm not asking anyone to do my "homework". I can research it myself (and I'll share my results if I have to go that way) . But if a Robocopy expert can guide me through this, I'd appreciate it.

Alternatively, if there's a great way to do this with some other tool, I'd welcome that pointer too. Robocopy has the advantage of being built in, however.

Also, I see that the question [Preserve all timestamps when moving data from one NTFS drive to another](https://superuser.com/questions/1366084/preserve-all-timestamps-when-moving-data-from-one-ntfs-drive-to-another) includes guidelines on preserving time stamps, but it doesn't address user file ownership issues or unreadable files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the robocopy that comes with Windows 10/Server 2016 and later. Older versions may have differences in options. (Microsoft changed this a couple of times.)

`Robocopy /COPYALL /MIR /Z /MT source destination`

/COPYALL will copy as much file meta-data (like timestamps, security and auditing data) as possible, but sparse files will not be sparse anymore after the copy (that is the one thing that robocopy can't do).
/MIR and /Z will recreate the folder-structure including any empty folders (and allows you to break of the command and restart it later with the same parameters. It will then only copy the missing parts.)
/MT enables multiple threads which makes the copy go a lot faster.
If you are using links (junctions and/or symbolic links) you want to add /SJ and /SL options as well to preserve those as links (otherwise the file/folder they reference will be copied in stead of a new link made).

/R:xxx and /W:yyy control the number of retries if a file can be read and the wait period between retries. You probably want to set /R to 2 or 3, because it defaults to 1000000.

And don't forget /LOG:filename so you can figure out which files couldn't be copied later. Note that filename can't include a path. File will always be written to current directory.

And DON'T try to copy the "System Volume Information" and other special system files located in the root of the disk! It's pointless and may really screw up the target filesystem if you try it anyway. Pagefile.sys, hiberfil.sys, swapfile.sys, the Recovery folder, the OneDriveTemp folder and the $RECYCLE.BIN folder go in that category as well.

*Please note: If the disk is about to fail this big copy-job may be enough to kill it completely.*

Comment: Thank you for the thorough reply. I just started the copy process seven minutes ago, and it seems to be working. The log file sure is verbose. I'll probably have to do some processing on it before I reload from the cloud backup. But so far this looks like a best answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to copy sparse files that leaves them sparse?

Comment: @Steve I don't know of any tool that can do that (besides making an actual exact clone of the entire filesystem). It is in theory possible by parsing the NTFS meta-data and determining which clusters of the file are sparse. Then you open the target as sparse file and copy the non-sparse parts of the source and replace the sparse clusters with seeks in stead of writing them. But even that won't get you an exact duplicate of the file if the source and target are on filesystems with different cluster-sizes. Lot of effort for little gain. Sparse files are very rare anyway. Why bother?

Comment: I don't know whether I have any sparse files anywhere. I'd guess not. I was just curious.