# Can LastAccessTime be set to an old timestamp using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I am using PowerShell to create test files for testing the output of Robocopy logs. To get different combinations of newer and older files, I am setting the file timestamps in the source and destination. However, I am unable to control the LastAccessTime attribute, which is preventing me from creating a file that Robocopy sees as completely identical ("same").

I can set CreationTime and LastWriteTime to any timestamp. But setting the LastAccessTime only refreshes the LastAccessTime to the current date and time.

```
$Item = New-Item "test.txt" -Force -Value "test"
$Item.CreationTime = "2000-01-01"
$Item.LastWriteTime = "2000-01-01"
$Item.LastAccessTime= "2000-01-01"  # doesn't work
Set-ItemProperty -Path "test.txt" -Name LastAccessTime -Value "2000-01-01"  # also doesn't work
$Item = $(Get-Item -Path "test.txt")  # refresh the $Item otherwise we see a phantom update of LastAccessTime
Write-Host "$($Item.CreationTime)  $($Item.LastWriteTime)  $($Item.LastAccessTime))"
```

I expected the output to be:

`01/01/2000 00:00:00  01/01/2000 00:00:00  01/01/2000 00:00:00`

But the actual output was:

`01/01/2000 00:00:00  01/01/2000 00:00:00  06/11/2022 17:29:35`

If I wait a few seconds and then re-run the last three lines, the LastAccessTime will be changed to the current date and time again.

Is there a way to set the LastAccessTime with PowerShell?

Comment: Answered here: [How to modify Last Write Time and Last Access on folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31240721)

Comment: You will want to do something like `LastAccessTime -Value $($LastAccessTime) ...` in order to achieve your goals.

Comment: @DavidPostill I forgot to mention that I tried Set-ItemProperty as well. It's a very weird case with that. If you check the value of $Item.LastAccessTime after Set-ItemProperty then you see the new set date, but in Windows Explorer and if you use $(Get-Item -Path "test.txt").LastAccessTime then you see the old access timestamp. I'll update the question with the weirdness.

Comment: @Jim - Are you refreshing the folder? When you modify a file, say opening a text file in notepad, the folder refreshes automatically.  However, due to you not actually opening and modifying the file, you might have to refresh the folder.  Now you likely can automatically perform this action with a PowerShell command.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, even if I close the Explorer window and then open again to check, I still see the non-updated value. But that's also confirmed by PowerShell - if I use $(Get-Item -Path "test.txt").LastAccessTime it confirms that the timestamp was not successfully set to the old timestamp. Running $(Get-Item -Path "test.txt").LastAccessTime repeatedly also shows that just accessing the timestamp through PowerShell is not resetting the timestamp. The two methods of setting the LastAccessTime have only 1 effect: they set the LastAccessTime to the current datetime rather than one specified.

Comment: @Jim - Just hit F5, closing the window, isn't required to refresh the file explorer window.

Comment: @Jim How about if you task kill explorer and then relaunch, doe the `LastAccessTime` update then? You can run from cmd `taskkill /f /explorer.exe` and then run `explorer.exe` now check and see if it's the correct timestamp. Check out https://superuser.com/questions/1366084/preserve-all-timestamps-when-moving-data-from-one-ntfs-drive-to-another/1366126#1366126 too. You might need to append in the time stamp portion too rather than just the date so change it to the datetime stamp rather than the date and see if that helps as well.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I tried with time as well but it didn't help. I don't think this is an issue on my system, you can run the same repro script as me and see what happens - the LastAccessTime resists being modified. There does seem to be some kind of timing effect. When I ran the repro script this morning, then I saw the timestamp modified. But re-running $(Get-Item -Path "test.txt").LastAccessTime after a pause shows the timestamp revert to the current time (though running that command does not itself update the LastAccessTime - it doesn't change no matter how often you run it).

Comment: hey @Jim Did you look over the different answers on the post I linked already too. It might be worth admin elevated running [`fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0` or `fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 1`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-behavior), rebooting the system with each of those changes you test, and then see if that helps shed some light. Using format `$(Get-Item $fl).lastaccesstime=$(Get-Date "05/12/2020")` seems to work for files not folders when I tested though.

Comment: @Jim Couple other posts too: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/139015-enable-disable-ntfs-last-access-time-stamp-updates-windows-10-a.html and  https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/129/enable-last-access-time.html

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Yes, thanks I did check out that answer but the Set-ItemProperty approach doesn't work for LastAccessTime. It works for LastWriteTime and CreationTime but not for LastAccessTime. Hmm, I don't want to change that fsutil setting because I'm just trying to create test files for robocopy, I don't want to change my system behaviour. Btw, are you sure that the change actually took with $(Get-Item $fl).lastaccesstime=$(Get-Date "05/12/2020") - because when I try that the change is only visible for <1 sec before it goes to current timestamp. https://i.imgur.com/A7JJYyN.png

Comment: Maybe it's impossible to set LastAccessTime. Even robocopy does not copy the LastAccessTime from source to destination. If I run robocopy, then touch the source file and then wait a bit and then run robocopy again, the LastAccessTime is updated to the time at which robocopy ran *for both files*, meaning that when robocopy updates the LastWriteTime, the LastAccessTime gets set to *current* time on both files, instead of the dest taking src value. https://i.imgur.com/8MK8peg.png

Comment: Could it be something related to the folder in use or powershell version? **[Why does it work for me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdPx9.png)**

Comment: @iTwasnTme Thanks for trying on your system. That's so strange that it works for you. I have the same version as you. I have seen it very _briefly_ report the changed date on my system but then re-querying shows an updated timestamp. What happens if you re-check $(Get-Item "test.txt").LastAccessTime after waiting like 2 seconds? This is my version stuff: https://i.imgur.com/ZpnEEKA.png and the disappearing LastAccessTime: https://i.imgur.com/jc4t6in.png I don't have any anti-virus other than Windows Defender, so don't see that any other process would touch the file.

Comment: @iTwasnTme hahaha, ok, mystery solved... I fired up Procmon and had a look at what was happening to the file. Sure enough, I see SearchProtocolHost.exe accessing the file after the timestamp was modified. I guess each time the timestamp gets updated, the SearchProtocolHost.exe comes along to re-index it and that updates the LastAccessTime. Re-running my test in an un-indexed directory yields a completely stable LastAccessTime and confirmed by Procmon showing no other processes touching the file. Thanks a lot for the help! (Thanks Vomit as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 3 file timestamps (CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime) can be set with PowerShell.

The timestamps can either be set via the property, or by using the Set-ItemProperty cmdlet. Examples of valid ways to set any of the 3 timestamps:

```
$Item = New-Item "test.txt" -Force -Value "test"
# all equally valid ways to set timestamp:
$Item.CreationTime = "2000-01-01"
$(Get-Item "test.txt").LastWriteTime = "2000-01-01"
Set-ItemProperty -Path "test.txt" -Name LastAccessTime -Value "2000-01-01"
# see the result
Get-Item "test.txt" | Select CreationTime, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime | Format-List
```

**Note** that setting the LastAccessTime can be unstable because other processes may read files when their timestamps are updated, and thus trigger the LastAccessTime to be updated. Possible culprits that update LastAccessTime include SearchProtocolHost.exe or anti-virus software.